# PG::Error: ERROR: column schema_migrations.version does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I installed CartoDB based on this instructions: http://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

When I run:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get the next error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column schema_migrations.version does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations...
               ^
: SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateLdapConfiguration
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: have you run `rake db:create`?  Try that, then migrate.

Comment: When I run rake db:create I get:

Ignoring statsd, because there were a error loading the config
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "carto_db_development" already exists
[sequel] Created database 'carto_db_development'
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "carto_db_test" already exists
[sequel] Created database 'carto_db_test'
carto_db_development already exists
carto_db_test already exists